# How to solve the issue of "This iPad hasn't been backed up in 9 weeks" preventing all UI on the iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an iPad Pro running iOS 9, and it just showed:

> This iPad hasn't been backed up in 9 weeks

and this popup box is preventing all UI of the iPad Pro, including the shut down slidebar, which won't react to sliding it.  Must I force shut down it by "Power button" plus Menu button for 5 seconds?  Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot dismiss the message and or cannot shutdown the iDevice normally by pressing the "Sleep/Wake" button for approximately five seconds and then slide the "Slide to Power Off" slider, then you have no choice but to do a hard reset.

Hold the "Sleep/Wake" and "Home" buttons simultaneously for around 10 seconds to reset the iDevice.

Comment: sigh... why has Apple software quality deteriorated so much... I have my iPhone 
Bluetooth jammed up and can't talk to my car for more than 2 dozen times as well